# Как ловить ошибку и выводить её?

Tags: c++, ввод, обработка-ошибок

как ловить ошибку с помощью try,catch если пользователь ввел в год(int) какой-либо текст(char,string) и выводить что-либо.

```
int year;
cin >> year;
```

Comment: `try {}  catch() {}`?

Comment: @ПавелЕриков, дело то понятное, но как это будет выглядеть все вместе?

Comment: Вы приведите пример кода, чтобы можно конкретно ответить на ваш вопрос.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков, привел.

Comment: Вообще если вы вводите строку вместо ожидаемого числа, то вы получите `year = 0`. Так что самое простое это сделать проверку на `year = 0`. Для вас будет является ошибкой, если пользователь введет `123world` например? Просто в этом случае в переменную `year` запишется, только `123`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А если вам не нравится `year = 0` (например если переменная `year` может принимать такое значение), тогда вот пример отлова ошибки:

```
int year;
cin >> year;
if (cin.fail()) {
    cout << "Ошибка ввода!" << endl;
} else
    cout << year << endl;
```

Хочу заметить, что если пользователь введет `123world`, то ошибки не будет, а в переменную `year` будет записано `123`

Answer (score 3):

Я как-то, фрилансируя :), для студентов набросал такой способ чтения с обработкой ошибок, смотрите, может, пригодится :)

```
int inputInt(const char * prompt, int m = INT_MIN, int M = INT_MAX)
{
    int N;
    for (;;) {
        std::cout << prompt << " (целое от " << m << " до " << M << "): " << std::flush;
        if ((std::cin >> N).good() && (m <= N) && (N <= M)) return N;
        if (std::cin.fail()) {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cout << "Неверный ввод, повторите.\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "Число вне допустимого диапазона значений. Повторите ввод.\n";
        }
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    }
}

a = inputInt("Введите размер массива",1,10);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    ::std::cin.exceptions(::std::ios_base::failbit bitor ::std::ios_base::badbit bitor ::std::ios_base::eofbit);
    try
    {
        int year{};
        ::std::cin >> year;
        ::std::cout << "success";
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        ::std::cout << "error";
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/1ETs1Y