# Как правильно сделать проверку try/catch?

Tags: c++, try-catch

Хочу заполнить массив элементами `double` вот так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
{
    cout << "Введите " << i + 1 << " элемент массива: ";
    cin >>array[i];...
```

Как правильно оформить проверку через `throw-try-catch` чтобы код переходил в `catch`, если введена буква или символ?

Comment: правильно этого не делать. Вам это обязательно?

Comment: А что написано в учебнике в главе про try..catch?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1221470/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b5%d1%91/1221482#1221482

Comment: @Эникейщик у меня ничего. Стивен Прата C++. Учился по видео на ютубе этой теме

Comment: Жаль, что это единственный источник информации по теме. Вот бы кто придумал и написал в интернете какие-нибудь обучающие примеры. Ah, wait!...